# CSS terminology: targeting complex combinations of tags

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to figure out what to call tags in CSS in order to build nice paragraphs.

For now, this is what my code looks like:

```
p {
font-size: 1em;
line-height: 1.25em;
margin: 0;
text-align: left;
}
p + p {
text-indent: 2.5em;
}
li p, blockquote p {
    margin: .5em 0;
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<p><strong>A little title</strong></p>
<p>Content text which can be single line or big block aswell.</p>
```

Referring to the code above, I want to call the

```
     <p><strong>g</strong></p>
```

content, so that it doesn't inherit from `p` as previously entered.

**I tried :**

`p strong` which do call every `strong` located in a `p` but only inside of it. I mean : only on `strong`, after the `p` container has been set. Could maybe work with negative margin but a bit messy ...

`p:not(p strong)` which sounds like a solution, but doesn't fit that case since the `strong` is still heriting from the `p` styling.

Is there any way to do this with CSS?

--- EDIT ---

I used the `p >strong:only-child` for now, which is calling the `strong` tags located alone in `p` tags. To give the good visual rendering, I applied a negative left margin of the indent size ... as a temporary solution.

Comment: The keyword is "select".

Comment: Should you really be using `<p><strong></strong></p>` for a title? There are tags for that already: `<h1>, <h2>, <h3>, <h4>, <h5>, <h6>`.

Comment: I know ... this is all coming from a big mistake. As the big amount of content I'm dealing with was already written this way, I'd like to find a durable solution to it.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try `p:not()`. Further documentation is here: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-not

**Update:** Unfortunately the `strong` part continues to inherit the `p` tag styling. Your best bet would be to clear it in a selector such as `p strong` and then apply the rest of the styles that you want there.

**Update 2:** Turns out you ARE able to use the `:not` psuedo-selector. An example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Mf5uc/1/

Comment: Could you describe the meaning of `p:not(p strong)` ? 
And yet, just in case `:not()` cannot contain compound selectors.

Comment: `p:not()` isn't the answer here, as I've learned. This documentation is a little more comprehensive though: http://kilianvalkhof.com/2008/css-xhtml/the-css3-not-selector/

Comment: Indeed Andrew. It is still inheriting from parent ... 
Anyway thanks for that info this can be really usefull in some situation despite not yet supported by all browsers.

Comment: `p:not(p strong)` is invalid. Even if it were valid, EVERY `p` isn't a `p strong` anyway...

Comment: Your fiddle does have the requirement that the `p` has a child element for it to work, otherwise the `p :not(strong)` rule won't do anything.

Comment: @BoltClock This is true. After further reading, it doesn't support compound selections, but it'll support classes and IDs.

Comment: @BoltClock The fiddle is updated here: http://jsfiddle.net/Mf5uc/1/ I used `p >strong` instead, which will apply the styles to only the `strong` tag. However, I believe it will still inherit properties.

Comment: Yep it does still inherit in good logic : it's strong you're calling, not p.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you want something like "contains":

```
p:contains(b) { line-height: 2em; }
```

but there is no such a selector in CSS in principle. 
If you want to know why then read my article "[CSS, selectors and computational complexity](http://www.terrainformatica.com/2008/07/css-selectors-and-computational-complexity/)"

Options for you:

a) Either to use classes like `p.header`, `p.normal` or

b) define style for the `<b>` rather than for `<p>` itself:

```
p > b:first-child:last-child {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

Let me know if you will need comments on `p > b:first-child:last-child` selector.

Comment: nice answer i'll try it and am reading you right now. 
Actually I want more something like 'only contains' as I want to call the strong tag which is alone caught in a p. I don't want to style a whole paragraph differently just because it contains a bolded word .

Comment: `:first-child:last-child` == `:only-child`. Also, `b` != `strong`

Comment: @Duke. As far as I understand you the selector `p > b:only-child` is exactly what you need, no?

Comment: the only child property allows me to target exactly the block i want, but just one hierarchical level too deep ... this is calling strong( or 'b' if you want) in the good cases. I just need to call that parent.